# Display the login form in the layouts main.php in Yii

Tags: yii

I want to change the the "views/layouts/main.php" to display the login form whenever the user isn't authenticated.

So I changed the "siteController" actionIndex like that:

```
public function actionIndex() {

$loginForm = new LoginForm();
    $this->render('index', array('loginForm'=>$loginForm)); 
}
```

And then call it in "views/layouts/main.php" like that:

```
if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest):
    echo $loginForm;
else :
    echo 'JJJ';
endif;
```

Then when I go to my website, It display the error: "Undefined variable: loginForm".

I don't know how to fix this? :(

Answer (score 0):

Define new property in your controller class:

```
public $loginForm;
```

In your `main.php` access it like:

```
echo $this->loginForm;
```

If you pass variable in your `render` method it will be available inside view file only, but not in layout file.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. The error disapear but the form doesn't displayed.

Comment: This form creates an object of a forms model class (www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model‎). It won't render the form. You need to do this explicitly, like in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

It's because *the index template is loaded before main template*. So, better way to do hat you want, is to define a public property in your Controller. I suggest you to define this property in Controller class because SiteController and *Controller extends it.

Then, you can run this.

```
if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
    echo $this->loginForm;
} else {
    echo 'JJJ';
}
```

Pay attention, because in this way of work you go out MVC pattern. This way of work force you to define a LoginForm in each action. I suggest you to do that:

Leave clean your calls to render file.

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $this->render('index'); 
}
```

And add a getLoginForm method in you Controller class obtaining:

```
if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
    echo $this->getLoginForm();
} else {
    echo 'JJJ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues here. Firstly, you are creating an object called `$loginForm` and assigning it a value of `new LoginForm();`

```
$loginForm = new LoginForm();
```

I'm not sure if you are doing this on purpose and `LoginForm()` is a function or a method that returns something, but I have a feeling you were intending to do:

```
$loginForm = new LoginForm;
```

Which creates a new instance of the **class** LoginForm (which is a default Yii webapp [CFormModel](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormModel) class). Even if that is the case, there are better ways to do this.

The easiest way is to call a `renderPartial` of the already existing *login.php* view (located in *protected/views/site/login.php*) inside your *index.php* view like so:

```
if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
    $this->renderPartial("loginform",array("model"=>new LoginForm));
} else {
    echo 'JJJ';
}
```

This renders the view *login.php* (without rendering the layout because we have already rendered the layout - [here's the docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController) on `render` and `renderPartial`) and pass it a new instance of the model `LoginForm` assigned to a variable called `$model`.

You will most likely have to edit the look of login.php view to make it "fit", but keep in mind that this view is being used in the *SiteController actionLogin* as well.

All that's left to do then is modify your *actionIndex* to handle the form submission (you can just copy the existing *SiteController actionLogin* functionality)

Another nicer solution would be to create a widget for the login form which can be used all over your application. I'm not going to go into that, but you can read up about it here on SO or check out [this tutorial](http://yiitutorials.net/easy/creating-a-widget-with-the-yii-framework) or [this one](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/portlet.menu).